# Format String to Timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp, type-conversion

How to format a timestamp coming as an Object to another timestamp format.

I want to convert-

```
"2014-3-16.8.6.57.323000000" (type is Object) into Expected : "Mar 16, 2014 6:57:10 PM" (type is String)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use this for convert current date and time as timestamp

```
Date d = new Date();
String dd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(d);
```

Comment: No luck. I need it in this format- Mar 16, 2014 6:57:10 PM.. and input is not any date or timestamp.. its Object.

Comment: you can use this format : String dd = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a").format(d);    it will give output as  Mar 21, 2014 10:41:54 AM

Comment: input is "2014-3-16.8. 6. 57.323000000". I am getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Its working now. Added try catch and provide proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date d= new Date(stamp.getTime());
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(d);
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it using the `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed.
Dual conversion was required--

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd.HH.mm.ss");
        try {
            Date d = df.parse("2014-3-16.8. 6. 57.323000000");
            Date d1 = new Date(d.getTime());
            String dd = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a")
                    .format(d1);
            System.out.println(dd);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```